# Socket.io on AWS API Gateway disconnected immediately after the successful connection

Tags: java, socket.io, aws-api-gateway, netty-socketio

I have implemented socket.io using netty-socket.io in Java and deployed it to AWS API Gateway.

When I try to establish a connection using the gateway WSS URL it getting disconnected immediately after connection.

NettySocketConfig.java

```
@Bean
public SocketIOServer socketIOServer() {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.setPort(5291);
        config.setContext("/socket");
        SocketIOServer socketIOServer = new SocketIOServer(config);
        return socketIOServer;
}
```

API Gateway configuration:
[image: API Gateway configuration]

And $Disconnect is configured with endpoint URL: http://{server.ip.adderss}:5291/socket with DELETE method type.

Trying to connect using gateway URL wss://{app-id}.execute-api.{region}.amazonaws.com/{stage} connected successfully but immediately disconnected.

It is working properly on the local server and on the client-server.

Is there any mistake in deploying the socket on Gateway?

Comment: Looking at your screenshot, do they have any other methods other then get and post? WSS are a persistent connection and I see you have the 'default' time selected so I'm curious if maybe it's dropping the connection

Comment: Yes, it supports ANY, HEAD, OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, and DELETE methods. The default time is for timeout if the server is unreachable that 30s, if I unselect it I have to provide custom timeout duration.